# How to display list of items in sets of two for each row

Tags: jquery, css, coldfusion

I am working with Bootstrap and Coldfusion and I was able to find code that allows me to display two items from the calendar and display them. However, it displays like so:

[image]

As you can see above, that is what I want however, if you look at the more event section, the events are not stacking up. I would like to have two events in one row and so on.

The image below is what I am looking for in terms of having 2 events in one row and so forth.

[image]

Another issue I am having is I am not able to display more then 2 events under the More Events section at a time and was wondering what I need to do to display at least 4 events at a time.

The end result I would like to produce is the following:
[image]

The following is the css and the colfusion code I am using (in advance, I apologize how ugly it looks. Going to clean it up soon):

```js
    <!--- Derived from: --->
     <!--- https://gist.github.com/stevewithington/18a6ef38e7234f1e1fc3 --->
     <!--- Upcoming events --->
     <cffunction name="dspDisplayEvents">
      <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="8C702325-155D-0201-11D851267D5B4B2B" />
      <cfargument name="maxMonths" type="numeric" default="3" />
      <cfargument name="groupDailyEvents" default="true" />
      <cfscript>
       var rs = '';
       var subRS = '';
       var local = {};
       local.feed = variables.$.getBean('feed').loadBy(name=arguments.feedName).setMaxItems(0).setNextN(0);
       local.listIDs = '';
       
       /* if ( feed.getIsNew() ) {
        return '<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Ooops!</strong> The Content Collection/Feed &quot;<strong>#HTMLEditFormat(arguments.feedName)#</strong>&quot; does not exist.</div>';
       }*/
       
       local.it = feed.getIterator(
        from=Now()
        , to=DateAdd('m', Val(3), Now())
        , maxItems=6
       );
      rs = local.it.getQuery();
      
     </cfscript>
     <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
       <cfoutput>
        <!--- #feed.getIsNew()# --->
        <!--- #local.it.hasNext()# --->
        <cfset ctr= 1 />
        <cfloop condition="(local.it.hasNext()) AND (ctr LT 4)">
         <cfset local.item = local.it.next() />
         <cfif not ListFind(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid'))>
          <cfif ctr eq 1>
           <!--- TODO: set a default image if no image is available --->
          <div class="bg-white1 centerEvent">
           <div class="hidden-xs override-col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 centerEvent margin-left">
            <p class="image-center upcoming-events-image image-padding"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
           </div>
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 expand-featured-event" id="featured-event">
     <table width="94%">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="4" class="eventCenter">
        <h4 class="featured1"><strong>FEATURED EVENT</strong></h4>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
        <hr class="hr" />
          </td>
       </tr>       
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="eventTop"> 
      <h6 class="ellipsis h6size"><!--- Title --->
    <div class="featured-event-title features">
              <strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong>
     </div>
     </h6>           
     <small>
     <!--- date --->
     <!--- start date --->
                #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#
  <!--- end date (if 'daily' event, and grouping is requested) --->
   <cfif YesNoFormat(arguments.groupDailyEvents)>
    cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS">
      select *
      from rs
      where rs.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
    </cfquery>
    <cfif subRS.recordcount gt 1>
<!--- end date --->
  <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS.displaystop)) />
<cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
  - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
   </cfif>
   </cfif>
    <cfset local.listIDs = ListAppend(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid')) />
        </cfif>
       </small>
        <small>
      <!--- Summary --->
      <div class="featured-event-summary">
      <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
          #local.item.getValue('summary')#
        </cfif>
       </div>
      </small>
         <a href="##"><small>Learn more &gt;</small></a>
       <br />
       </div>
      <cfelse>
     <div class="paddingMore">
     <cfif ctr eq 2>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 override-col-md-2 moreEventMargin">
          <small><strong class="featured moreCenter" style="margin-bottom:5px">MORE EVENTS</strong></small><br />
     </cfif>
        <div style="margin-top:5px">
                  <small>#LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#</small><br />
                  <small><strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong></small><br />
         </div> 
                     <br />
         </cfif>
        </cfif>
       <cfset ctr++ />
      </cfloop>
     </div>  
      </div>
             <button class="btn btn-info btn-md resizable buttonHome" type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://oc2-web03/regal_prod/index.cfm/news-events/events-calendar/'"><small>SEE ALL EVENTS &gt;</small></button><br />
            </div>
         </div><!---closes the bg-white1 div--->
        <!---<button class="btn btn-info btn-md resizable" type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://oc2-web03/regal_prod/index.cfm/news-events/events-calendar/'" ><small>SEE ALL EVENTS &gt;</small></button><br />
        </div>--->
       </cfoutput>
      </cfsavecontent>
      <cfreturn local.str />
     </cffunction>
```

```css
    /*----- general styles -----*/
    html, body { font-family: "OpenSans", sans-serif;background-color:#f9f9f9 }

    media (min-width: 1170px){
     body { width: 1170px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
     }
    }
    body { position: relative; }
    h1, h2, h3 { font-family: "UrgeText", sans-serif; }
    large, .large { font-size: 120%; }
    .text-black { color: #000000; }
    .text-gray { color: #888888; }
    .bg-white { background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    .bg-white2{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:214px;}/*07/15/2016*/
    .hr{margin-top:-1px !important; width: 118%;}
    .eventTop{margin-top:-40px;}
    .margin-right { margin-right: 30px; }
    .no-padding-right {  padding-right:0; }
    .no-padding-left { padding-left:0; }
    .no-margin { margin: 0; }
    .no-margin-right { margin-right: 0; }
    .moreEventMargin{margin-top:-2px; margin-left:-7px;}/*81px top*/
    .buttonHome{margin-top:31px; margin-left:369px;} /*-80px top*/
    .btn-standard {  
     border-color: #000;
     border-radius: 0;
     background-image: none;
    }

    .override-col-xs-offset-1{
     margin-left:14.333333%;
    }

    /*07/15/2016*/
    .image-padding{
     margin-top:34px;
     border:10px solid #f9f9f9;
    }

    /*07/15/2016*/
    .featured{
     color:#337ab7;
     padding-top:26px;
     
    }

    .featured1{
     color:#337ab7;
     padding-top:9px;
     
    }

    .features{
     color:#337ab7;
     padding-top:26px;
    }

    /*For Doctor Finder shift address Address2 @ROB*/
    .shiftAdd{margin-left:62px;}

    .shiftAddUrgent{margin-left:80px;}

    /*@ROB*/
    .padding{
     padding-bottom:2px
    }
    /*@ROB* 06/15/2016*/
    .ignore{

    }


    /*******************************************************/
    /*07/07/2016 comment out padding-bottom*/
    .navbarpadding {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .navbarapp-padding{
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .body-padding{
     margin-top:70px;/*Note: This is for Mura. For production, we would need to see the actual results.*/
    }

    .finder-padding{
      margin-top:50px;/*Note: This is for Mura. For production, we would need to see the actual results.*/
    }

    /*07/07/2016 called container fluid to add the margin between navbar and body content*/


    /*Full size of the calendar with no scroll bar 07/05/2016*/
    /*.fullheight{
     margin-bottom:500px;
    }
    /*07/06/2016 To remove the particular height from calendar*/
    /*.fc-scroller{
     height:auto !important;
    }*/

    /*07/11/2016 to increase the width of the background*/
    /*.bg-white1{
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     width:34.8%;
    }*/

    /*event mobile devices*/
    @media(max-width:650px){
     .centerEvent{text-align:center;}
     .moreEventMargin{margin-top:16px !important; margin-left:58px !important;}/*0px top and left 57px*/
     .buttonHome{margin-top:-21px !important; margin-left:0px !important;} 
     .bg-white2{background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 0px;}
     .margin-left{margin-left:0px;}
     .image-padding{
      margin-top:0px;
      border:10px solid #f9f9f9;
     }
     .margin-leftTable{margin-left:46px;}
     .eventTop{margin-top:-40px; margin-left:60px}
     .bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto; padding-bottom:10px;}/*07/15/2016*/
    }
    @media(max-width:650px) and (orientation:landscape){
     .hr{margin-top:-1px !important; margin-left:63px;}
     .featured1{
      color:#337ab7;
      padding-top:26px;
      margin-left:68px;
     }
     .hr{margin-top:-1px !important; width: 84%;}
    }

    @media(max-width:721px){
     .margin-left:{0px;}
     bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height: auto; padding-bottom:0px;}
     .buttonHome{margin-top:18px !important; margin-left:0px !important;}
    }

    @media(max-width:750px) {
     .centerEvent{text-align:center;}
     .featured1{
      color:#337ab7;
      text-align: center;
     }
     .moreCenter{
      text-align: center;
     }
    }

    @media(max-width:750px) and (orientation:landscape) {
     .buttonHome{margin-top:18px !important; margin-left:55px !important;}
    }

    /*allows the scroller to appear on mobile version 07/11/2016*/
    @media(max-width:480px){
     .fc-scroller{
      overflow-x:hidden !important;
      overflow-y: scroll !important;
      height:100px !important
     }
     /*07/15/2016*/
     .bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto; padding-bottom:20px !important;}/*07/15/2016*/
     .centerEvent{text-align:center;}
     .moreEventMargin{margin-top:20px !important; margin-left:16px !important;}
     .buttonHome{margin-top:0px; margin-left:2px;}
     .expand-featured-event{width:86% !important; }
     .image-padding{margin-top:0px;}
     .margin-left{margin-left:0px;}
     /*.fullheight{height:200px !important;}*/
     .image-padding{
      margin-top:0px;
      border:10px solid #f9f9f9;
     }
     .featured{
      color:#337ab7;
      padding-top:10px;
     }
     .margin-leftTable{margin-left:7px;}
     
     .eventTop{margin-top:-40px; margin-left:0px}
     
     .hr{margin-top:-1px !important; width: 103%;}
    }

     .override-col-xs-2, .override-col-xs-10{
      float:right;
      min-height:1px;
     }

    /*Expand Events on home page 07/11/2016*/
    @media (min-width:992px){
     .override-md-offset-3{
      width:3.5%; /*3%*/
     }
     .override-col-md-2{
      /*float:left;*/
      width:83.66666667%;
     }
     .paddingMore{margin-top:-90px; padding-left:220px;}
     .margin-left{margin-left:40px;}
     .bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto; padding-bottom:10px;}
    }

    @media (max-width:977px){
     .bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto; padding-bottom:0px;}/*07/15/2016*/
    }

    /*Change button color for slideshows override theme.min.css 07/05/2016*/
    .btn-info1 {
      color: white;
      background-color: #5bc0de;
      border-color: #46b8da;
      background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004377 0, #004377 100%);
      background-image:-linear-gradient(to bottom, #004377 0, #004377 100%);
      background-repeat:repeat-x;
      border-color:#00437;
    }

    .slideText{
     color:white;
    }

    /*Following is to center the 2016 copyright Regal ... footer*/
    @media (min-width:1200px){
     .override-col-lg-6{
      width:63%;
      margin-left:252px;
     }
    }

    /*****************************************************/
    /*override Theme.min.css file @ROB*/
    .navbar .navbar-nav:not(.ignore){
     padding-bottom:10px;
     margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .container-fluid.ng-scope:not(#home-content){
     padding-top:20px;
    }

    .break-all { word-break: break-all }

    /*Added by Rob 05/13/2016*/
    .calendarResize{width:100%;}

    /*Added by Rob 05/31/2016*/
    .fixIconCal{padding-left:0px;}

    .fc-left h2{
     font-size:22px;
    }

    /*If we are going to use a style sheet Added by @Rob*/
    @media print {
      .visible-print  { display: inherit !important; }
      .hidden-print   { display: none !important; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 450px){
     .has-margin-top { margin-top:20px; }
     .no-margin-top { margin-top:0; }
    }

    /*------ navbar.cfm, navbar_ap.cfm */

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
     header { height: 120px; }
    }

    .absolute-position {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; 
     left: 0;
     right: 0; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    @media (max-width: 480px){
     .fc-view-container{width:109%;}
     
    /*07/08/2016 Added the following so title is visible*/ 
     .visible-xs{
      display:block !important;
      margin-top:40px;
     }
     
    /*07/08/2016 Added the following so adjust indicators*/
     .carousel-indicators{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 15;
      width: 60%;
      margin-left: -30%;
      padding-left: 0;
      list-style: none;
         text-align: center;
     }
    }

    @media (max-width: 639px){
     .company-logo { width: 210px; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px){
     .company-logo { width: 300px; }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px){
     .company-logo { width: 400px; }
    }

    /*Added by Rob 05/13/2016*/
    @media (max-width: 800px){
     .fc-view-container{width:94%;}
     .buttonHome{margin-bottom:-21px; margin-left:489px; margin-top:-41px;}
     .moreEventMargin{margin-top:-92px; margin-left:211px;}
    }

    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar  { background: rgba(0,119,192,1); }

    .navKeywords { border-right-style: none; }

    .navKeywordsSubmit { 
     border-left-style: none;
     border-color: #000;
     }

    .navbar { 
     border: 0; 
     box-shadow: none; 
    }

    .well { 
     background-color: initial; 
     background-image: none; 
     border: none; 
     box-shadow: none; 
     padding-left: 0; 
     padding-right: 0; 
    }

    .well .nav-list .nav-list a{ 
     font-size: 90%;
    } 
    /*Added 06/15/2016 */
    @media (max-width: 1023px){
     .navbar-opacity {
      /*background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);*/
      background-color:#f9f9f9;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
      /*background:#f9f9f9;*/
      filter: initial;
      /* For IE 8*/
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
     }
     .navbar-opacity-home {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      /*background-color:#f9f9f9;*
      background:#f9f9f9;
      filter: initial;
      /*For IE 8*/
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
     }
     /*Added by Rob. Fixed the issue with footer being cut off in tablet and mobile sites*/
     .col-lg-2{
      position: relative;
      min-height: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
     }
    }

    @media (min-width:1024px){
     .navbar-opacity { 
      /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
      background-color:#f9f9f9;
      /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);*/
      background: rgba(249, 249, 249, .7);
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
     }
     .navbar-opacity-home { 
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color:#f9f9f9;
      /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);*/
      background: rgba(249, 249, 249, .7);
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
     }
    }



    @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .navbar { background-image: none; }
     
    }

    @media (min-width: 768) and (max-width: 1024){
     .navbar-header .container {
      width: auto;
     }
    }

    /*display image in mobile devices for News/Events page @ROB*/
    @media (max-width: 767px){
     .upcoming-events-image { 
      max-width: 180px;
      max-height: 180px;
      width:95%;
     }
     
     .hidden-xs.col-md-2{
      display:inline !important;
     }
     .fc-scroller{
      overflow: visible !important;
      display:inline-block !important;
      }
     .fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container{
      height:auto !important;
     }
    }

    /*Fixes the icon calendar @ROB*/
    @media(min-width: 968px){
     .icon-fix{
      margin-left:-15px;
     }
    }

    .navbar-nav > li > a { padding: 10px; }

    @media (min-width: 1024px){
     #navPrimary li a:link
     , #navPrimary li a:visited { color: black; }
     
     #navPrimary li.active a:link
     , #navPrimary li.active a:visited { color: #0077C0; }
     
     #navPrimary li a:hover
     , #navPrimary li a:active{ color: #0077C0; }
     
     #navPrimary li.first a{ padding-left:0; }
     
     #navPrimary li.last a{ padding-right:0; }
     
     .nav>li>a:hover{ 
      text-decoration:underline;
      background-color:transparent 
     }
     
     .nav-tabs>li>a:hover{ border-color:initial }
     
     #navStandard ul.nav li a:link
     , nav#navStandard ul.nav li a:visited { color: #808080; }
     
     #navStandard ul.nav li a:hover
     , nav#navStandard ul.nav li a.active { color: #0077C0; }
     
     #navStandard ul.nav li a.active { font-weight: bold; }
     
     .navbar .navbar-nav>.active>a {  
      background-color:transparent; 
      color: #0077C0;
     }
    }

    @media (max-width: 1023px){
     a.navbar-brand { padding-right: 0; }
    }

    .bw-button { 
      border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     }

    .radio-custom { display: none; }

    .radio-label-custom {
     border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
     margin: auto 1px;
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     padding-left: 3px;
     padding-right: 3px;
     padding-top: 2px;
     padding-bottom: 2px;
     line-height: 95%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .radio-custom:checked + .radio-label-custom {
     color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    /*------ end navbar.cfm, navbar_ap.cfm */

    /*----- home.cfm -----*/



    #homepage .carousel { margin-top:auto; }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
     #homepage .carousel .item{ height:650px; }
     
     #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
      left: 20px;
      top: 90px;
     }
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px){
    /*07/08/2016 Modified #homepage .carousel .item { height: 200px; } and added margin-top:85px*/
     #homepage .carousel .item { 
      height: 200px; 
      margin-top:85px;
     }
     #homepage .carousel .item img { 
      max-width: 100%; 
      height: auto; 
      display: block; 
     }
     
     #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
      left: 0;
      top: 35px;
      color: #0077C0;
     }
    }

    #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
     background-color: transparent;
     text-align: left;
     }


    @media (min-width: 1024px){
     #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
      left: 10; 
      top: 160px;
      width: 500px;
     }

     .carousel-caption h1
     , .carousel-caption h2 *{ color: #0077C0 }
     
     #homepage .carousel .item img{
      <!-- [if IE 9]>
       top:200px;

       width: 100%;
      <![endif]-->
     }
     
     .slideHeader {
      font-size: 40px; 
      color: #0077C0; 
      font-family: "UrgeText"; 
     }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1170px){
     #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
      left: 130px;
     }
    }

    /****************Carousel Expands. Carousel-caption and body content remains the same ROB*********************/
    @media (min-width:1281px){
        #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
            left:auto;
            right:auto;
            max-width:1263px;
            margin-left:70px;
        }
        .footer-links{
            margin:auto;
            max-width:1263px;
        }
        .bodyPages{
            margin:auto !important;
            max-width:1263px !important;
        }
        #searchForm{
            margin:auto !important;
            max-width:1263px !important;
        }
      /* body{
            /*max-width:1263px !important;
            margin:auto;
        }*/
     .depth-2 {
      margin: auto;
      max-width:1263px !important;
     }
     .depth-1{
      margin: auto;
      max-width:1263px !important;
     }
     /*.carousel-caption {
      max-width: 775.81px;
      margin: auto;
        }
     .row.item img{
      width:100%;
     }*/
    }
    /*********************************************************/

    @media (min-width:1263px){
     body{
      overflow-x:hidden;
     }
    }

    #home-content { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0 } 

    .quickLink {
     /*border: 1pt solid black;*/
     padding-bottom: 10pt;
    }



    .upcoming-events-image { 
     max-width: 180px;
     max-height: 180px;
     }

     .expand-featured-event{
      width:74%;
     }

    #featured-event, #more-events { 
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding: 15px 0px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px){
     #featured-event, #more-events{
      height: 214px;
      overflow: hidden;
     }
     
     #featured-event .featured-event-title {
      width: 170px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
     }
     
     #featured-event .featured-event-summary {
      width: 170px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
     }
    }

    /*----- end home.cfm -----*/


    /*----- inc/footer.cfm ----*/

    footer table{
     margin: 30px auto;
     border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 20px 20px;
    }

    footer td {
     vertical-align: top;
    }

    .footer-links {
     margin-top: 20px;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    /*Modified by Rob*/
    /*.row {
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }*/
    @media (max-width: 1023px){
     #footer-affiliation { 
      background-color: #0077C0; 
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
      padding: 5px;
     }
     
     #footer-affiliation a { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px){
     .footer-column { margin-right: 20px }
    }
    .fc-time{display:none;}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please take your time to properly indent and clean up your code.

Comment: @Alex Okay I will do that then

Comment: @Alex it has been done

Comment: If you want to put a line break (or some similar formatting) after every 2 events, you should look into the MOD operator. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html

Comment: @TRose Right but if you look at the code above, after it eq 2, it stops and I thought if I changed the value it would generate more results but it didnt. Also, how would I implement MOD. Based on example I am seeing, I would need to create a variable and store how many items have gone through. Would I need to do something similar? If so, how would I keep track?

Comment: You need to read up on operators.  The `eq` and `mod` operators are very different. Equals only matches a *single* value.  Whereas `modulus` is more flexible. It checks the remainder of dividing two numbers. Meaning it could be used to determine if the current row is evenly divisible by some number (like 2 or 4). Then if it is, do something special like start a new row. ie `<cfif theCurrentRow MOD 2 EQ 0>do something here</cfif>`. BTW, duplicate threads are discouraged on S.O.  Voting to close as a duplicate, since you have already opened several threads on this same topic.